# How to map discrerte values to a heatmap in seaborn?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, seaborn

I am trying to plot discrete values in a heatmap using seaborn. Here is the list I am trying to plot:

```
xa = [[5, 4, 4, 4, 13, 4, 4],
 [1, 9, 4, 3, 9, 1, 4],
 [4, 1, 7, 1, 5, 3, 7],
 [1, 9, 4, 3, 9, 5, 4],
 [2, 1, 4, 1, 9, 4, 3],
 [9, 4, 8, 1, 7, 1, 9],
 [4, 8, 1, 7, 1, 4, 8]]
```

Here is the code that I am using to plot the heatmaps:

```py
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
from matplotlib.colors import ListedColormap
data = np.asarray(xa)
sns.heatmap( data,cmap=ListedColormap(['green', 'yellow', 'red']))
```

My question is how do I plot each number to a specific colour. The range of values will be from 1-17. So 17 different colours one for each number. I did read some other answers but none of them talked how to assign a number a specific value. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, you can do something like this:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.colors as c
data = np.asarray(xa)
colors = {"white":1, "gray":2, "yellow":3, "lightgreen":4, "green":5, "lightblue":6, "blue":7, "lightcoral":8, "red":9, "brown":10,
          "violet":11, "blueviolet":12, "indigo":13, "khaki":14, "orange":15, "pink":16, "black":17}
l_colors = sorted(colors, key=colors.get)
cMap = c.ListedColormap(l_colors)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.pcolor(data[::-1], cmap=cMap, vmin=1, vmax=len(colors))
# plt.axis('off') # if you don't want the axis
plt.show()
```

For each number corresponds a color, starting from 1 (white), 2 (gray), till 17 (black). As you can see there are no blacks in the image because there are no 17s in your array and the colormap is not normalized.

[image]

Or with `seaborn`:

```
data = np.asarray(xa)
colors = {"white":1,"gray":2,"yellow":3,"lightgreen":4, "green":5, "lightblue":6, "blue":7, "lightcoral":8, "red":9, "brown":10,
          "violet":11, "blueviolet":12,"indigo":13, "khaki":14, "orange":15, "pink":16, "black":17}
l_colors = sorted(colors, key=colors.get)
cMap = c.ListedColormap(l_colors)
sns.heatmap(data,cmap=l_colors, vmin=1, vmax=len(colors))
```

[image]

If you want all ticks on the legend, add this:

```
ax = sns.heatmap(data,cmap=l_colors, vmin=1, vmax=len(colors))
colorbar = ax.collections[0].colorbar
colorbar.set_ticks([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17])
```

[image]