# How to conditionally define color for each cell in matplotlib/seaborn heatmap?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, seaborn

I have a seaborn heatmap and I want to define a custom color for each cell conditionally. For example, if the cell value is 60, then I would like its value to be green.

Or, Is there way to define a numpy array structure of the color which is as in same shape and size of the data so that we can directly pass that color while plotting the data?

My data structure is:
[image]

Where any single row's data i.e. data[10
] is:
[image]

Comment: Yes, such is certainly possible. One approach would be to create a 2d array of values `0,1,2,...` and use a seaborn palette with the same number of colors. Can you elaborate some test data to show the types of conditions you want to work with? Is your input integer or float? Probably similar questions and answers on stackoverflow can be helpful.

Comment: @JohanC My data have a large structure of around 45*50.  I updated the data structure in the question. And my motive is to color each cell differently based on their values or it's best if I can create a array of colors of same shape as that data which I can just pass when plotting.

Comment: Note that posting data as image instead of as text [isn't recommended at stackoverflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question). Also, it is strongly preferred that you post some example code of what you tried.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57892473/how-to-map-discrerte-values-to-a-heatmap-in-seaborn This answers the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your data are just multiple of 10 and between 0 and 60, you can use them directly to draw a heatmap.

You can provide 7 colors, for example 6 colors of a standard colormap and one special color for value 60. Here is some example code. `vmin` and `vmax` are set to make the colorbar automatically set the correct values near the colors.

You can also just use a list of 7 colors, something like `colors = ['dodgerblue', 'gold', 'lime', 'purple', 'turquoise', 'orange', 'crimson']`, or use a colormap with distinct colors (e.g. `cmap=sns.color_palette('tab10', 7, as_cmap=True)`).

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np

data = np.random.randint(0, 7, (45, 50)) * 10.0

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8, 5))
colors = sns.color_palette('mako', 6) + ['crimson']
sns.heatmap(data=data, cmap=sns.color_palette(colors, as_cmap=True), vmin=-5, vmax=65, ax=ax)
# sns.heatmap(data=data, cmap=sns.color_palette('tab10', 7, as_cmap=True), vmin=-5, vmax=65, ax=ax)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: heatmap with value 60 colored differently]

Here is an approach for 14 numbers. `np.unique(data, return_inverse=True)` returns an array with all the unique values and also a mapping with positions of which value goes where. These positions are given as a 1D list, which needs to be reshaped again to 2D. The `'tab20'` colormap has maximum 20 different colors, although some colors might be hard to distinguish. See [here](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/colors/colormaps.html#qualitative) for a list of qualitative colormaps.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np

# values between -11 and 61, maximum 15 different values
data = np.random.choice(np.random.randint(-11, 61, 15), (45, 50))
values, positions = np.unique(data, return_inverse=True)
positions = positions.reshape(data.shape)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(14, 7))
colors = sns.color_palette('tab20', len(values))
N = len(values)
colors = sns.color_palette('tab20', N)
# or you can give your own list: colors = ['red', 'green', ....][:N]
sns.heatmap(data=positions, cmap=sns.color_palette(colors, as_cmap=True), vmin=-0.5, vmax=N - 0.5,
            annot=data, fmt='.0f', annot_kws={'size': 6},
            cbar_kws={'ticks': range(N)}, ax=ax)
fig.axes[-1].set_yticklabels(values)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: heatmap with 14 colors]

Comment: Does this answers your question?

Comment: Not yet, sorry for this. My data is not uniformly distributed to be considered multiple of 10 as some points can be 64 or 61 or 58 or even 59 and some are -11, and each of these points need different color. I am not able to solve this as of yet.

Comment: How many different colors do you need? Can you edit your post and add more information? Note that more than about 12 colors will be very hard to distinguish visually.

Comment: Around 12 at least which can go to 14 at some cases, what I am trying in a different approach is: Creating a numpy array of the same shape and size as the data where each cells holds color that corresponds to the heatmap using matrix. And passing that color using: cmap1 = matplotlib.colors.ListedColormap(grid_cell_colors.flat). But the color is not getting rendered correctly.

Comment: Not exactly but I found another solution that exactly met my requirements and fixed it too. Thank you for the help.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57892473/how-to-map-discrerte-values-to-a-heatmap-in-seaborn

Comment: It is indeed quite similar to this answer; you can also use the trick of subtracting and adding 0.5 to get the ticks for the colorbar right. If you post a question, it would really help to fully explain the requirements.